# Form in React not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a small app with React and Bootstrap. Trying to have a page (Home Component) with only a form showing. The bundle is VALID, but all I see is a blank page with all the other components missing. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';

export class Home extends React.Component {
render() {
 return(
  <div>
    <form>
     <div className="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email address:</label>
       <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email"></input>
     </div>
     <div className="form-group">
       <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
       <input type="password" className="form-control" id="pwd"></input>
     </div>
     <div className="checkbox">
       <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</input></label>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: does the console logs any errors ?

Comment: Yes, seems the error comes from the input. `Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of Home.`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Seems the problem was in closing tags and missing value in the checkbox input type. Here's the code.

```
import React from 'react';

export class Home extends React.Component {
render() {
return(
  <div>
     <div className="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email address:</label>
       <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" />
     </div>
     <div className="form-group">
       <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
       <input type="password" className="form-control" id="pwd" />
     </div>
     <div className="checkbox">
       <label><input type="checkbox" value="remember" />Remember me</label>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Login</button>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your here - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1208/)

Replace `for` attribute with `htmlFor` and the `input` should be self-closing.

For a quick reference -

```
class Home extends React.Component {
render() {
 return(
  <div>
    <form>
     <div className="form-group">
       <label htmlFor="email">Email address:</label>
       <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" />
     </div>
     <div className="form-group">
       <label  htmlFor="pwd">Password:</label>
       <input type="password" className="form-control" id="pwd" />
     </div>
     <div className="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" />
       <label htmlFor="chkbox">Remember me</label>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
}
}
      React.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('container'));
```